# Most efficient way to draw a bunch of 3d lines in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I need to plot a list of 3d lines in matlab. What is the quickest way to do that?
I am currently doing something like

```
%edges is a MX2 matrix, holding the list of edges
%points are the vertices' coordinates
hold on; %so all the lines will be saved
for i=1:size(edges,1)
    a=edges(i,1); %get first point's index
    b=edges(i,2); %get second point's index
    p=[points(:,a) points(:,b)]; %construct a 3X2 matrix out of the 2 points
    plot3(p(1,:),p(2,:),p(3,:)); %plot a line
end
```

But this is not only slow during the actual loop, but also at the end, the resulting plot is very slow and irresponsive when I try to, for instance, rotate it using the drag & rotate tool.

I know the same plot using opengl etc would run much faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this (caution - brain compiled code...)

```
figure;
patch('faces', edges, 'vertices', points, 'edgecolor', 'b');
axis equal;
```

Where `edges` should be an `Nx2` matrix of indices and `points` should be an `Mx3` matrix of coordinates (the transpose of your `points` array).

From my experience, calling `patch` directly can be significantly faster than repeated calls to `plot`.

To give some idea, the times to generate 1000 randomly generated line segments, using my (admittedly old!) MATLAB 7.1 are as follows:

1. Calling `patch`: 0.03 seconds.
2. Calling `plot`: 0.5 seconds.

**EDIT**: One way to get the edge colour behaving as you want (specifying a single colour per edge) is to introduce duplicate vertices as follows:

This works-around the issue that the edge colour can only be specified indirectly via vertex colour data. If we were to rely only on the vertex colours then all edges sharing a common vertex might end up with the colour assigned to that vertex - check out the *'flat 'edgecolour* description [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html).

```
%% a "star" shape, so that we can really see what's going on 
%% with the edge colours!!
pp = [0,0,0; 1,-1,0; 1,1,0; -1,1,0; -1,-1,0];
ee = [1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 1,5];

%% important - only 1 colour known per edge, not per vertex!!
cc = (1:size(ee,1))'; 

%% setup a new set of vertices/edges/colours with duplicate vertices
%% so that each edge gets it's correct colour
nnum = 0;
pnew = zeros(2 * size(ee, 1), 3); %% new vertices
enew = zeros(1 * size(ee, 1), 2); %% new edge indices
cnew = zeros(2 * size(ee, 1), 1); %% new edge colours - via vertices
for j = 1 : size(ee, 1)
    n1 = ee(j, 1); %% old edge indices
    n2 = ee(j, 2);
    enew(j, 1) = nnum + 1; %% new edge indicies into pnew
    enew(j, 2) = nnum + 2;
    pnew(nnum + 1, :) = pp(n1, :); %% create duplicate vertices
    pnew(nnum + 2, :) = pp(n2, :);
    cnew(nnum + 1) = cc(j); %% map single edge colour onto both vertices
    cnew(nnum + 2) = cc(j);
    nnum = nnum + 2;
end

%% Draw the set efficiently via patch
tic
figure;
hold on;
patch('faces', enew, 'vertices', pnew, 'facevertexcdata', cnew, ...
    'edgecolor', 'flat', 'facecolor', 'none');
plot(pnew(:,1), pnew(:,2), 'b.');
axis equal;
toc
```

It would be nicer if MATLAB allowed you to directly specify the edge colour data - but it doesn't seem to support that...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a chance you can also show me how can I send an array of colors so that each edge would be colored with a different color?

Comment: @noam: There are a few different colouring options, depending on what you want. You can use the `'facevertexcdata'` parameter to set interpolated colours from the vertices - type `edit trimesh` to get an idea along these lines. If you just wanted a few flat colours (`'b', 'k', 'r', etc`) I guess you could break the edges into a few different groups and choose a single colour for each group - I'm assuming here that you have many more edges than colours. There may be other options - check the documentation...

Comment: I actually need to color each edge with a different color, out of many colors (Say I am displaying the stress exerted on all the support beams of some structure). So I need to specify the color by edge, not by vertex, and I can't break the edges into several different groups as there are a lot of colors...

Comment: @noam: It seems you can get individual edge colours, but only indirectly from vertex colour indexing - check out the `edgecolor` section here http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html. Unfortunately, I'm not sure it can do what you want...

Comment: @noam: Check the two solutions I added: one using LINE with a single color, the other using SURFACE for multicolored lines..

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [LINE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/line.html) low-level function, using `NaN` to plot as separate segments:

```
%# sample graph vertices and edges (similar to your data)
[adj,XYZ] = bucky;
[r c] = find(adj);
edges = [r c];      %# M-by-2 matrix holding the vertex indices
points = XYZ';      %# 3-by-N matrix of points X/Y/Z coordinates

%# build a list of separated lines
e = edges';
e(end+1,:) = 1;
e = e(:);
p = points(:,e);
p(:,3:3:end) = NaN;

figure
h = line(p(1,:), p(2,:), p(3,:));
view(3)
```

This is very efficient as it creates a single line object. Now you can customize the line, but it is restricted to have one color for the entire thing:

```
set(h, 'Color',[.4 .4 1], 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',10, ...
    'MarkerFaceColor','g', 'MarkerEdgeColor','g')
```

[image: line]

---

According to the comments, if you want to have each edge in your graph in a specified color, consider the following code instead. It involves using the [SURFACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface.html) function:

```
p = p';                      %'# transpose the above p for convenience
clr = (1:size(p,1))';        %'# for each edge, color index in current colormap
figure
surface(p(:,[1 1]), p(:,[2 2]), p(:,[3 3]), [clr clr], ...
    'EdgeColor','flat', 'FaceColor','none')
colormap( hsv(numel(clr)) )  %# specify your colormap here
view(3)
```

[image: surface]

Comment: The `surface` solution is the closest to what's asked, but if you check http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html, it again seems that the `edgecolor` is only set indirectly via the vertex colour data (It implies all edges per face share the colour of the lowest numbered vertex), rather than specifying a colour for each edge directly - which is what is wanted. Based on a quick check, this seems to give the same behaviour as the `patch` solution. Maybe I missed something??