# Plotting multiple 3D rectangles using patch in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, patch

I have x, y, and z coordinates of multiple rectangles' corners. All coordinates are in one matrix; ordered as x, y, z. Every three columns contain one rectangle's four corner coordinates. I want to show all rectangles in one plot. However, it does not show any of rectangles. Here is my code:

```
%Coordinates(1,3*i-2:3*i) = top left corners' x y z coordinates
%Coordinates(2,3*i-2:3*i) = down left corners' x y z coordinates
%Coordinates(3,3*i-2:3*i) = down right corners' x y z coordinates
%Coordinates(4,3*i-2:3*i) = top right corners' x y z coordinates
```

This code works fine...
    [~,c] = size(coordinates);
    for i = 1:3:c
        patch(coordinates(:,i),coordinates(:,i+1),coordinates(:,i+2))
        hold on
    end

Comment: When you say that all coordinates are in one matrix, you mean that the matrix is size `P*3x1` (a 1D matrix, or an array) or are they in `Px3` format?

Comment: coordinate = [xTL yTL zTL; xDL yDL zDL; xDR yDR zDR; xTR yTR zTR];
TL, DL, DR, AND TR are acroynms for top left, down left, down right, top right

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right, you're looking for somthing like the following solution. The idea is taken from Amro's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139485/1797098).

## Idea

The code first creates vectors with start and stop vertices. It then creates a matrix holding lines with the start vertex, stop vertex and inserts a `nan` line. Then it uses `patch` to plot a surface and makes the face invisible. Note, that for reeeaally many vertices, this "wastes" some memory for the `nans` but the patch command is quite fast, as it creates only one object.

## Code

```
% Sample coordinates
coord = [ 1  -1.3  -1;...
         -1  -1.3  -1;...
         -1  -1.3   1;...
          1  -1.3   1;...
          1   1.3  -1;...
         -1   1.3  -1;...
         -1   1.3   1;...
          1   1.3   1;...
         -1.3   1  -1;...
         -1.3  -1  -1;...
         -1.3  -1   1;...
         -1.3   1   1;...
          1.3   1  -1;...
          1.3  -1  -1;...
          1.3  -1   1;...
          1.3   1   1;...
          1    -1  -1.3;...
         -1    -1  -1.3;...
         -1     1  -1.3;...
          1     1  -1.3;...
          1    -1   1.3;...
         -1    -1   1.3;...
         -1     1   1.3;...
          1     1   1.3];

nlines = size(coord, 1);
% Vectors for vertices
X = zeros(2, nlines);
Y = zeros(2, nlines);
Z = zeros(2, nlines);
C = zeros(1, nlines);
% One iteration per vertex
for ii = 1:nlines
    % Here comes the edge back to the first vertex
    if mod(ii,4) == 0
        X(1, ii) = coord(ii, 1);
        Y(1, ii) = coord(ii, 2);
        Z(1, ii) = coord(ii, 3);

        X(2, ii) = coord(ii-3, 1);
        Y(2, ii) = coord(ii-3, 2);
        Z(2, ii) = coord(ii-3, 3);

    % Here come all other edges
    else
        X(1, ii) = coord(ii, 1);
        Y(1, ii) = coord(ii, 2);
        Z(1, ii) = coord(ii, 3);

        X(2, ii) = coord(ii+1, 1);
        Y(2, ii) = coord(ii+1, 2);
        Z(2, ii) = coord(ii+1, 3);
    end
    % One color for each rectangle
    C(ii) = floor((ii-1)/4);
end
% Insert nans between lines
X(end+1, :) = nan;
Xf = X(:);
Y(end+1, :) = nan;
Yf = Y(:);
Z(end+1, :) = nan;
Zf = Z(:);
% Setup patch matrix
p = [Xf, Yf, Zf];                   
% Prepare color matrix
r = repmat(C.', 1, 3)';
clr = r(:);
% Make a figure
f = figure;
% Plot patch
surface(p(:,[1 1]), p(:,[2 2]), p(:,[3 3]), [clr clr], ...
    'EdgeColor',    'flat', ....
    'FaceColor',    'None')

grid on
view([55, 36]);

xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```

## Plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am still dot understand fully how your data is saved, but let me try with what I understood:

```
[~,c] = size(coordinates);
hold on
for ii = 1:1:c/4
    patch(coordinates(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4,1),coordinates(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4,2),coordinates(1+(ii-1)*4:4+(ii-1)*4,3));
end
```

If this does not work, please post an example of your data so I can actually try it.

NOTE: do not use `i` as variable name in Matlab, as it is the imaginary unit.