# The Wall: Display vertical planes in the Matlab Map Environment

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure, geo

I want to plot vertical planes in geo-projected figures from the Matlap Mapping toolbox. Imagine four vertical faces of a cube like in [this example](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/multifaceted-patches.html) resembling [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046205/plotting-multiple-3d-rectangles-using-patch-in-matlab). The problem is that Matlab doesn't plot all faces correctly as you can see in the example below:

[image: Example Cube with a missing face and overlapping base]

Minimal code example using `geoshow`:

```
xf = [ 0, 1, 1, 0;
       1, 1, 0, 0;
       1, 1, 0, 0;
       0, 1, 1, 0  ]
   
yf = [ 0, 0, 1, 1;
       0, 1, 1, 0;
       0, 1, 1, 0;
       0, 0, 1, 1 ]
    
zf = [ 0,   0,   0,   0;
       0,   0,   0,   0;
      .01, .01, .01, .01;
      .01, .01, .01, .01 ]
   
figure
axesm('miller');
geoshow(xf,yf,zf,'DisplayType','surface','FaceColor','red','FaceAlpha',0.4);
xlabel('lat')
ylabel('lon')
zlabel('alt')
view(-140,-60);
```

The [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geoshow.html) for geoshow says:

> geoshow(lat,lon,Z) projects and displays a geolocated data grid.
>
> Z: M-by-N array. May contain NaN values.

My guess is that the `Z` variable must be defined differently, but how? Or is there another solution? I really feel like ramming my head against the wall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things going wrong in your example:

1. MATLAB is drawing faces you don't want because you have *four rows* in `xf`, `yf` and `zf` ... edges are drawn between horizontally and vertically adjacent points.
2. The last column of `xf` (similarly `yf` and `zf`) should be the same as the first, to "close" the box (i.e. draw the one vertical wall you're missing)

**My solution:**

After some playing, it looks like one solution is to define your `xf`, `yf`, and `zf` as follows:

- `zf` = 2-by-n matrix, top row all zeros, bottom row all the desired height of the walls (for you, 0.1; for my example below, 1)
- `xf` = 2-by-n matrix, top and bottom rows identical, giving the latitude coordinates of the square defining your region
- Similarly, `yf` = 2-by-n matrix, top and bottom rows identical, giving the longitude coordinates of the square defining your region.

Important notes:

- the first and last columns of `xf`, `yf`, and `zf` should be identical to "close" the room
- `xf` corresponds to latitude which is actually `y` coordinates here, and vice-versa for `yf`

**One Wall:**

Just trying to get a feel for `geoshow` I started with one wall:

```
geoshow([1 1; 1 1], [0 1; 0 1], [0 0; 1 1], ...
        'displaytype','surface','facecolor','red','facealpha',0.5);
view(3); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

Notice the first input (all 1's) corresponds to the *y-values*, since they are latitudes: 
[image: One wall]

**Two Walls:**

I added another column to each `xf`, `yf`, and `zf`:

```
geoshow([1 1 0; 1 1 0], [0 1 1; 0 1 1], [0 0 0; 1 1 1],... 
        'displaytype','surface','facecolor','red','facealpha',0.5);
view(3); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

[image: Two Walls]
(note: I adjusted the axis here to match the first picture for consistency)

**Three Walls:**

I added another column to each `xf`, `yf`, and `zf`:

```
geoshow([1 1 0 0; 1 1 0 0],[0 1 1 0; 0 1 1 0],[0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1],...
         'displaytype','surface','facecolor','red','facealpha',0.5);
view(3); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

[image: Three Walls]
(note: there is no top on the "box")

**Four Walls:**

I added another column (a copy of the first column) to each `xf`, `yf`, and `zf`:

```
geoshow([1 1 0 0 1; 1 1 0 0 1],[0 1 1 0 0; 0 1 1 0 0],[0 0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1 1],...
         'displaytype','surface','facecolor','red','facealpha',0.5);
view(3); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

[image: Four Walls]

**Ta-da!** To convince you there's no top on the box:
[image: No Top!]